# How to extract comments body from GitHub with Python

Tags: html, github, comments, github-api, github-api-v3

I would like to extract only the bodies of comments of the issues with the API v3 (but I am also open to new solutions).

For now I tried to enter this address: (example) https://api.github.com/repos/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/comments?per_page=50&since=2018-02-19T00:00:00Z&until=2019-04-20T00:00 : 00Z

After entering the address I read all the data (HTML) but GitHub does not allow you to view more than 100 results at a time. Can this limit be exceeded? Can only the comment bodies be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub's API offers [pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination). You can't request more than 100 comments in a single request, but you can make multiple requests to retrieve more than 100 comments:

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the `?page` parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the `?per_page` parameter.

The API also includes a [`Link` HTTP header](https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header) that tells you about interesting pages, e.g. what the `next` and `last` pages are.

> Can only the comment bodies be obtained?

I'm not aware of any way to do this using the v3 / REST API. It may be possible using the [v4 / GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/issuecomment/), but please note that this uses a completely different model.